# SUMIF indirect excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

I am working to create a formula that adds the value of cell K207 on 12 different sheets and stores it in a cell. I have created the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT($E$31:$E$34&"!J207:J208"),K27,INDIRECT($E$31:$E$34&"!K207:K208")))
```

where INDIRECT is looking at the sheets stored from E31:E34 and looking at the values from J207:J208 on each sheet to see if it matches the CRITERIA, with is the value stored in cell K27. Then, INDIRECT repeats this process, going through the sheets stored in cells E31:E34 and summing the values from K207 to K208 if the value matches K27. In this case, only the value in J207 will match the value in K27.

The problem arises when I try to modify this formula to only add the value IF it is a number. The 12 sheets in the range to be looked at have not all been created yet, and I want to update the formula when the sheets are added to the workbook without any manual interaction.

I thought about adding IF(ISNUMBER('sheet1'!K207),'sheet1'!K207,0) somewhere to the formula, as this worked to manually do the process listed above. .

Comment: the sumif will ignore non number cells in the sum range.  No need to add a check.

Comment: I am getting a reference error, which led me to believe there is an error. Looking at the calculation steps shows that the reference error is occurring in the last statement in the indirect

Comment: Then the sheet name in that last cell does not exist.

Comment: I am trying to add sheets that haven't been created so that the formula updates when the cells are created.

Comment: Then wrap with IFERROR(): `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SUMIF(INDIRECT($E$31:$E$34&"!J207:J208"),K27,INDIRECT($E$31:$E$34&"!K207:K208")),0))` depending on version one may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: That worked! Thank you I would not have thought of that